# How to determine if an object is between two other objects in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, collision

I have a screen filled with circles. One circle is the player, one is the enemy, and the others are obstacles. I want the enemy to be able to calculate if there is an obstacle in the path of a straight line from the player to the enemy, so it can adjust accordingly (it is taking place in space, so it is a straight line for jumping from asteroid to asteroid).

Right now, I just turn a random direction when the AI is stuck on an asteroid.

Comment: For Stack Overflow questions, it is always advised to post some code showing your problem, or showing what you have tried.  Stating a problem with no apparent research effort is going to get you downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be find the `Vector2` between player and enemy (using `Vector2.Subtract`), and then divide it into smaller vectors or reduce it to a delta that you choose. This can be done normalizing the distance vector and multipling it by a fixed number.
Then simply add that delta to the enemy position and check if the new position collides with an objects (maybe using `Rectangle.Contains` method), and do this until you reach the player.